# How to determine convergence/divergence using either root test, ratio test or comparison test?

Tags: limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to solve if this limit converges or diverges using either root test, ratio test or comparison test, but i dont really know where to start. Would anyone like to give me a hint?

The only thing i can think of when i see it is that the denominator will grow faster than the numerator and therefore it will converge, but that is just my gut feeling, without proving it.

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k-1}{k^2\sqrt{k+1}}$

Edit: I've how updated to the correct summation, it was not a limit. I misread the question, its just about determine conv./div.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. There is no $x$ in $\dfrac{2k-1}{k^2\sqrt{k+1}}$. Besides: is this a problem about sequences or about series?

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{2k-1}{\sqrt{k+1}}<\frac {2k}{\sqrt k}. $$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{2k-1}{k^2\sqrt{k+1}} = \lim_{k\to\infty}\left( \frac{2}{k\sqrt{k+1}} - \frac{1}{k^2\sqrt{k+1}}  \right)= 0$$

because the denominator of both terms approaches $\infty$ for $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Root, ratio and limit tests are tests for the convergence of series ($\sum_{k=1}^\infty$), not sequence limits.